# How can I get the player coordinates in Minecraft

Tags: java, minecraft-modding

I am currently working on a client for Minecraft Java edition and I'm having an issue finding out how I can get my Minecraft character's current coordinates, client side coordinates.

I would just like to know where I can find the file that contains the coordinates, or a way to get the coordinates, without using forge, or anything like that. Just vanilla Minecraft. The Minecraft version I am working with is 1.8.9, but I would like this to work for any version of the game.

Comment: If you want to improve your question, please use the edit link at the bottom, rather than deleting and re-posting the question. To SE's backend, that looks like an attempt to abuse the system, and it can lead to automated restrictions on your account.

Comment: A friendly suggestion: if you have trouble writing to a file, then maybe writing your own minecraft client now isn't the best thing to do with your time. I'd suggest learning java first. You wouldn't try to run a restaurant without knowing how to cook.

Comment: Bálint, I know how to write to a file, I'm having trouble finding out where I can get the coordinates to write to a file.

Comment: @Farmer The title of this question makes it sound like you can’t figure out how to output to a file - if you changed it to something like : “How can I GET the player coordinates in Minecraft”, that might eliminate this confusion and may also yield more answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only thing that I found to work was to use the debug menu. When you hit f3 it opens the debug menu. From there I was able to take a screen shot of the coordinates, and use the Tesseract API to translate the image into text, and then log it to a file.